# MongoError: server does not support collation

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, collation, pagination

I am using mongoose paginate v2 to retrieve documents from mongodb collection in version 3.2.7.

```
var options = { page, limit };

Schema.paginate(query, options);
```

page (1) and limit (10) are values passed to paginate the result. and query is all files ({}).

when doing so, I am getting the following error:

```
MongoError: server 127.0.0.1:27017 does not support collation.
```

How can I set collation available for only 1 particular db inside mongo?

Comment: What does options and query contain? What is the db version?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet added more details. version 3.2.7

Comment: [collation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/) has been introduced in the mongodb 3.4. You have to upgrade  it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**`collation`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/) has been introduced with the mongodb version **3.4** and above. You have to upgrade mongo in order to use it.